# can't open external hard drive on ubuntu and windows

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a 3TB external HDD which has two partitions.
one has 1TB and another one has 2TB.
I primarily use ubuntu 21.10 and also have windows 10.

when I want to open it it says `the folder is empty`.
On windows, it says `the drive is not accessible.`

**The issue:**
while I was copying files to HDD, the HDD has been disconnected. Since then, I have the issue.

`sudo lsblk -f`:

```
sdb                                                                                    
├─sdb1 ntfs           Hadi         B8804E4B804E0FF4                      221.5G    76% /media/mahdi/Hadi
└─sdb2 ntfs           Mahdi Jafari 525A788D5A787019                      989.4G    47% /media/mahdi/Mahdi Jafari
sr0
```

I have important data in my HDD. Is there any way to securely fix HDD?

`NOTE:` I already had `Parot OS`. the `Parot OS` can open HDD.

Comment: If you can't open it on either OS, then the file system might be corrupted. The disk could also be failing.  Because you are using NTFS on both partitions you should use `chkdisk` in Windows. Ubuntu has `ntfsfix` but I would not suggest using Ubuntu to fix file system problems in NTFS,

Comment: Definitely run `chkdisk` from Windows

Comment: Thank you @Nmath and PonJar. I did run `chkdisk` on Windows and it fixed the issue. Now, the problem is solved.